# Sharing data to client whenever API has results available?

Tags: responsive-design, architecture

I have the following scenario, can anyone guide what's the best approach:

```
Front End —> Rest API —> SOAP API (Legacy applications)
```

The Legacy applications behave unpredictably; sometimes it's very slow, sometimes fast.

The following is what needs to be achieved:

```
- As and when data is available to Rest API, the results should be made available to the client
- Whatever info is available, show the intermediate results.
```

Can anyone share insights in how to design this system?

Comment: Who will be the consumers of the event data be?  I.e. internal consumers you have some degree of control over or third parties?  Do you know how many consumers you'll have, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You want some sort of event-based API that the API consumers can subscribe to.

Event-driven architectures come in many forms - from event notification ('hey, I have new data, come and get it') to message/payload delivery; full-on publish/subscribe solutions to that allow consumers to subscribe to one or more "topics", with event back-up and replay functionality to relatively basic ones.

If you don't want a full-on eventing platform, you could look at WebHooks.

A great way to get started will be to start familiarizing yourself with some event-based architecture [patterns](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-driven-architecture.html).  That last link is for Chris Richardson's website,  he's got a lot of great info on such architectures and would be well worth a look.

In terms of the defining the event API, if you're familiar with [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/), there's [AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/) which is the async equivalent.

In terms of solutions, there's a few well known platforms, including open source ones.  The big cloud providers (Azure, GCP and AWS) will also have async / event based services you can use.

For more background there's this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) (which I have not read - so can't speak for it's quality but it does look detailed).

**Update: Webhooks**

Webhooks are a bit like an ice-berg, there's more to them than might appear at first glance.  A full-on eventing solution will have a very steep learning curve but will solve problems that you'll otherwise have to address separately (write your own code, etc).  Two big areas to think about:

1. Consumer management.  How will you onboard new consumers?  Is it a small handful of internal systems / URLs that you can manage through some basic config, manually?  Or is it external facing for public third parties?  If it's the latter, will you need to provide auto-provisioning through a secure developer portal or get them to email/submit details for manual set-up at your end?
2. Error handling & missed events.  Let's say you have an event, you call the subscribing webhook - but there's no response (or an error).  What do you do?  Do you retry?  If so, how often, for how long?  Once the consumer is back up what do you do - did you save the old events to replay?  How many events?  How do you track who has received what?

**Polling**

@Arnon is right to mention polling as an approach but I'd only do it if you have no other choice, or, if you have a very small number of internal system doing the polling, i.e - incurs low load, and you control both "ends" of the polling; in such a scenario its a valid approach.

But if its for an external API you'll need to implement throttling to protect your systems, as you'll have limited control over who's calling you and how much.  Caching will be another obvious topic to explore in a polling approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  For the scenarios wherein we do a full transition to full-blow event-driven architecture, does "Webhook" fit in the bill?

Answer (score 1):

you have several options to do that

1. polling from the UI - will require some changes to the API, the initial call will return a url where results will be available and the UI will check that out everytime
2. [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) - will require changing the api
3. [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) - essentially keeping the http connection open and pushing new results as they are available - sounds the closest to what you want

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insights.

Comment: Polling will work but is not an efficient model and does not scale - every polling request will take up bandwidth and consume computing resource at the API providers end.

Comment: depends on the  actual needed scale as well as the implementation. I like evens over request-reply communications but there's no need to over engineer solutions